# Matching a list of accounts with Salesforce accounts

Tags: account

I am relatively new to Salesforce. I am struggling to get a solution for my task. I am given a list of 100 accounts (which do not have Salesforce IDs and are obtained outside from Salesforce). I need to find if these 100 accounts are present in Salesforce and if there is a match I need to obtain their Salesforce IDs so that we can continue to work on our project.  It's basically matching the given accounts with accounts in our org. So do you have any knowledge how can I match them so that I would be able to obtain their IDs?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have this list in **csv** format, you can match the Accounts on the basis of Account names. But please note, **it is possible that multiple accounts may be operating with the same name. In that case, you will be confused which Account to pick up**.

I don't think there is anything you can do with apex, this process has to be **manual**. You can follow something like this:

1. You need to identify few fields (3 or 4) on the Account whose **combination** always yields a **unique** value. Create a **new column** of this unique combination on the excel sheet.
2. Now, you need to export the Accounts using a **dataloader**. It is possible your ORG may have large data volume, so I would suggest you to export the data keeping in some filter condition. **Don't forget to include Account id in the export as well because that's what we need**. After you have the export, **combine** the same fields to generate a **unique** column.
3. Now you have two different file with same unique column. You can now easily utilize **VLOOKUP** functionality of excel to get the Account Id of the matched accounts.

I hope that works for you.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. Yes the file is in csv format. But when I verify, the fields on accounts in sales force don't match with the file header names. I think this csv file is taken from some other source completely and they are asking me to find a match. In step 1, I understand that I need to merge 3or4 header names to create a unique value. is that so.?

Comment: It will be difficult for you find a match if the fields on Account doesn't match with the file header names. You need to contact that person who created that file to get more information. You can also consider using Account Number if the names are different. This seems to be  a tedious task.

Comment: Yes that's the whole problem. There is no account number too. If at least, the header names matched, we could have used your way.

Comment: @Mike - I am not sure what else to look for. This is indeed a big problem. There has to be at least one matching field and header name.

Comment: The field  for Account name in salesforce is "Account Name" where as in the file " Company name" is given. If even this doesn't match I don't know how other fields would match.

Comment: "Company name" is a field on Lead. After the Lead is converted to Account, "Company name" of Lead becomes the "Account name" of Account. May be this is the field you can use to match up with Account name. But again, as I said it is possible you will find duplicate names. You should start and see how far you get.

Comment: I searched fields on lead, I could find the field Company and not Company name. Do you think that would do.?

Comment: Go to SetUp > Customize > Lead > Fields. You will see "Company". It's a text field.

Comment: I know how to search for a field. I was saying that the header name in the file is "Company name" whereas the field on the Lead is "company". I asked if that would be good enough to create unique value.

Comment: I don't see any other option. Try for few accounts first.

Comment: I guess I have to merge atleast 2 fields. But I am unable to find even one field which are similar( Between salesforce and the given list). I hope if there is some possibility. Lets see.

Comment: @Mike Please talk to person who created this. You should not working on something that already has high percentage of hitting errors.